# How to get :id param of child route from parent component in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes, route-parameters

I'm trying to get the `:id` param defined in

```ts
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'orders',
    component: ListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'view/:id',
        component: ViewComponent
      },
    ]
  }
])
```

from `ListComponent`.

I already tried:

```ts
route: ActivatedRoute

route.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = +params['id'];
})
```

from `ListComponent`, but the `params` array is empty, I suppose it's because the `:id` param belongs to `ViewComponent` not `ListComponent`.

How can I get the `id` param in `ListComponent`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use the `firstChild` property or the `ActivatedRoute` to get the child route:

```ts
route.firstChild.snapshot.params['id']
```

Comment: looks like the property routerState doesnt exist on ActivatedRoute, also i wanna get the id inside parent component not child component so i used route.firstChild.params

Comment: I misread the question a bit and assumed @run yards answers what you actually want. I updated my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: I used route.snapshot.firstChild, not route.firstChild.snapshot
Also check firstChild is defined first

Comment: I am getting error params of null in parent comenent if i use the above answer , what is the proper lifecycl hook to get that

Comment: The lifecycle hook doesn't matter. You subscribe to params as shown in the question and then your callback gets called when params are updated.

Comment: yes , But I am loading my child route in one click function, so i am unable to catch child params before child loads , so i wrote above subscription i am getting error in console

Comment: There won't be child params before the child is loaded. You can for example inject ActivatedRoute to the child component and make the child component pass the params to a shared service.

Comment: it's working but i am getting error in console ilke "ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'"

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'snapshot' of null` also in method `ngOnInit`

Comment: I guess it's better to create a new question with your code

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think all you need to do is update your answer to be `route.snapshot`. Something must have changed or you got it wrong in your original answer. For example I just ran this code with Angular 5.2 and it worked `_this.route.snapshot.firstChild.params['id']`

Comment: FYI this worked for getting grandchildren ... this.route.firstChild.firstChild.snapshot.params['id']

Answer (score 26):

To get the child's params inside the parent component, i used the firstChild property of ActivatedRoute, because i only have on child route

```
route: ActivatedRoute

route.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = +params['id'];
});
```

Comment: The only correct answer, because things never happen in sync in Angular, and this answer covers the subscription (async) part as well.

Answer (score 4):

Recursively finding child params wont always get you the params you are looking for. Specially when moving routes around.

Instead, an RxJS `ReplaySubject` can be used to publish the current child id.

Create a new service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChildIdService  {
  current$ = new ReplaySubject<number>();
}
```

Import it on the child component and subscribe to the replay subject:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ar: ActivatedRoute, public ci: ChildIdService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.ar.params.map(params => +params.id).subscribe(this.ci.current$);
  }
}
```

Import the service on the parent component and use the async pipe to subscribe to the child value:

```
<span>Mother component child ID: {{ci.current$ | async}}</span>
```

Here is a working snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8xome (add /child/42 to the browser app preview to see it working)

---

Alternatively define the components as siblings and add the parent as a componentless route, ex.: https://vsavkin.com/the-powerful-url-matching-engine-of-angular-router-775dad593b03 under "Sibling Components Using Same Data"

Comment: Any particular reason for using ReplaySubject instead of other kinds of Subjects? I'm still trying to grasp the usecases for them, so understanding it in this example would help.

Comment: ReplaySubject will memorize the previous result, making the observable hot for any future subscriptions.
This is helpful if you subscribe to this observable in more than one place, and want to access previously pushed results.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep digging through the `route.firstChild.params['id']` if there is just the one child route or use something like `route.children[0].children[1].params['id']` to dig through multiple levels using bracket notation to access sibling routes. Its a bit of trial and error when it comes to finding the correct level.

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing this is adding the following in the parent component:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="routerOutlet.isActivated && routerOutlet.activatedRoute?.paramMap | async as paramMap">
child id is: {{paramMap.get('id')}}!
</ng-container>

<router-outlet #routerOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

of course, it would be nicer to use have resolver at the child instead of params

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="routerOutlet.activatedRouteData['child'] as child">
child id is : {{child.id}}
</ng-container>

<router-outlet #routerOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

assuming child route has something like:

```js
// ...
resolve: {
 child: 'childResolver',
},
```

and the child resolver can be in some module:

```js
// ...
providers: [{
    provide: 'childResolver',
    useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => ({
      id: route.paramMap.get('id')
    })
  }],
```